# broadleafcommerce demo site maven install - build fail

Tags: maven, broadleaf-commerce

I am facing an issue with `maven install` for broadleaf commerce demo site--

> setup[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.mycompany:core:jar:1.0: Failed to collect
>   dependencies at
>   org.broadleafcommerce:broadleaf-framework:jar:4.0.0-GA: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for
>   org.broadleafcommerce:broadleaf-framework:jar:4.0.0- GA: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.broadleafcommerce:broadleaf-framework:pom:4.0.0-GA from/to public
>   releases (http://nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nex
>   us/content/repositories/releases/): Failed to transfer file:
>   nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/broadleafcomme
>   rce/broadleaf-framework/4.0.0-GA/broadleaf-framework-4.0.0-GA.pom.
>   Return code is: 500 , ReasonPhrase:Internal Server Error. -> [Help 1]

I think the http://nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ is down. Can someone suggest some alternative?

Comment: You should post your pom.xml, that'll help us in debugging the issue.

Comment: hi, did u solved this problem ?